# Jquery Autocomplete - add selected values to hidden field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using Jquery Autocomplete based on: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/. I am able to select a value from the textbox and add it to a list as in the example. Is it possible to add the selected value to a hidden field? For example `<input type='hidden' value='value 1,value 2, value 3' name="SelectedValue" id="SelectedValue"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add more than one value to a hidden field:

```
var hdnValue = $('hdnFieldName').val();
$('hdnFieldName').val(hdnValue +','+selectedValue);
```

Have a look at [string.join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input#suggest').result(function(event, data, formatted) {
   $("#SelectedValue").val( $("#SelectedValue").val() + "," data );
});
```

Look over [autocomplete documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result#handler) for details

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel. Just use this piece of jQuery. For each autocomplete input field it creates a hidden field using the original input field's name. In that hidden field the autocompleted key is stored. On submit the keys will be submitted. You don't have to change anything to your backend.

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/756.cfm

```
$('input.YourClassName').each(function() {
    var autoCompelteElement = this;
    var formElementName = $(this).attr('name');
    var hiddenElementID  = formElementName + '_autocomplete_hidden';
    /* change name of orig input */
    $(this).attr('name', formElementName + '_autocomplete_label');
    /* create new hidden input with name of orig input */
    $(this).after("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + formElementName + "\" id=\"" + hiddenElementID + "\" />");
    $(this).autocomplete({source:'employee-search-json.cfm', 
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var selectedObj = ui.item;
            $(autoCompelteElement).val(selectedObj.label);
            $('#'+hiddenElementID).val(selectedObj.value);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```